# Publishing webapp into local Liberty Stuck from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, websphere-liberty

I have a Dynamic Web App in Eclipse deploying into a WebSphere Liberty pluging.
It was deploying fine until I create an Ant file to build an EAR file.

After that automatic Deploy Stuck on 80% of the publishing process
Stay with Msg:
Publishing : myEAR: Waiting for application status from the server.

I remove the ant file but anyway.
What can I do to make Eclipse work as before.

Answer (score 0):

If stuck at about 80% eclipse is usually waiting for the server to print a message saying that the application was started.  Do you see a message in the console view similar to the following?

[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application Web2EAR started in 0.048 seconds.

If not is there anything in the console view or in the server logs to indicate what might have gone wrong with the application deployment?

Comment: Nothing is shown in the console nor server logs. Only the Eclipse Progress bar indicate that is in 80% and stay there.

Comment: If you open the Progress view can you cancel the deploy?  Once cancelled is the application actually deployed (you can check in the apps directory for your server)?
<p>
Is there anything in the workspace .log file (<your workspace>/.metadata/.log)?
<p>
If you switch the loose config mode does it work?  Double click on the server in the Servers view to open the server editor.  Toggle the Run applications directly from the workspace checkbox and then try to deploy again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this problem by double clicking on the server and unchecking the "run Applications Directly From Workspace" option.

My environment is slightly different. My project is both a Maven Project and a Dynamic Web Project. And I added the Maven dependencies to the Deployment Descriptor.